# Javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: Sent Items not found

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Hello im trying to retreive emails sent by my outlook mail but i have a prob in the folder name
I can retreive my mail inbox using the folder "Inbox" but i want the sent items folder

```
final String username = "XXXX@outlook.fr";  
    final String password = "XXXX";
        Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");        
props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(true);
        try {
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("outlook.office365.com", username, password);
            

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Sent Items");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("To: " + message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
            }
            inbox.close(true);
            store.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

```
avax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: Sent Items not found
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkExists(IMAPFolder.java:455)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1068)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1001)
    at com.jsf.com.SendEmail.read2(SendEmail.java:61)
    at com.jsf.com.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:11)
```

Comment: You don`t created folder "Sent items"

Comment: @WBLord i didn't got what u mean ?

Comment: Maybe you got the name "Sent Items" wrong?

Comment: @g00se in outlook there is a folder named "Sent items"

Comment: I would check the IMAP url. Not sure where you'd find that

Comment: @g00se it not a url prob because when i changed the folder name to "inbox" it works very well and i retreive my inbox emails

Comment: You misunderstand. Folders are hierarchical and are not necessarily where you think they are. [IMAP urls](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/mit-scheme-9.2/mit-scheme-imail/IMAP-URLs.html) reflect that and might be a better guide to where the folder *actually* is. You can also address the folder by its url instead of its name

Comment: I tried to use the url of folder but it doesnt work

Comment: It's called 'Sent' in my Outlook/IMAP setup.

Answer (score -2):

```
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.